# Having a SO Careers in the drop down?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, user-interface, careers, top-bar

I have noticed the SO Careers tab in the drop down list of sites like ServerFault, etc

[image]

As SO careers also have data scientists and analyts careers in them, would it be sensible if we also have that drop-down?

Wanted to have a discussion with the community folks before asking a question on the Meta SE site.

---

Wasn't sure about the relevant tags for the question, please modify the question, if you find any relevant tags missing.

Comment: I would be interested to see how many people on CV use SO Careers, to be completely honest I haven't seen that many. Saying that, I do, and would be supportive of this idea.

Comment: @ChrisC That's because a chunk of users here, are academicians, but I'm pretty positive, there are data science professionals here, who might benefit from it. Let's wait for what the community has to say.

Comment: "Academics", I believe, but it's a good point.

Comment: I added answers to collect the votes polling style.  Let me know if you want them deleted.

Comment: @Erik Thank you.  Seems good to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the response received, the question/request has been [posted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/267374/having-so-careers-in-the-drop-down-for-crossvalidated) on the Meta site.

Yes votes:      11 (11+, 0-)

Neutral Votes:  3 (4+, 1-)

No Votes:      -2 (0+, 2-)

Answer (score 13):

## Yes!

This is a grand idea.

Answer (score 2):

## Meh.....

I don't really care either way.

Comment: This is my vote, but I can't vote on my own answer.

Answer (score -2):

## No!

This is a terrible idea.